# How many ways to fill 1xn board with tiles of 2 different sizes?

Tags: combinatorics

If I have a board of size 1xn and two different types of tiles, 1xa and 1xb, how many different ways can I fill the board?

Comment: In other words, are you looking for the number of pairs of $(x,y),\,x,y\in\Bbb N$ that satisfy the equation $$ax+by=n?$$

Comment: Not exactly because I am interested in the positions of the blocks not just the number of each. For example if n=10 a=2 and b=4 then 244, 424, and 442 would all be instances I would want to count.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by building a recurrence equation. If $T(n)$ denotes the number of ways to tile a board of size $1$ x $n$ then:

$T(n) = T(n - a) + T(n - b)$

where base conditions are:

$T(x) = 0$ if $x < a$ and $x < b$ and $ x != 0 $

$T(0) = 1 $